# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.keys ()

Tags: node.js, express

**I think there's something  wrong with the keys !** 
it says : at Function.keys () there's an error but i dont find it please someone help me out with this .

```
    router.patch('/users/:id',async (req,res) =>{
    const _id = req.params.id
    const updates = Object.keys(req.body)
    const allowedUpdates = ['name','email','password','age']
    const isValidOperation = updates.every((update) => allowedUpdates.includes(update))

    if(!isValidOperation)
    {
        return res.status(400).send({error : 'You are not authorized'})
    }
    try 
       {
           const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(_id,req.body,{ new : true,runValidators: true})
           if(!user)
           {
               return res.status(404).send()
           }
           res.send(user) 
        }
         catch(e)
         { 
            res.status(400).send()
             }
})
```

Comment: can you also attach the stack trace.

Comment: YOU ERROR IS HERE...  const updates = Object.keys(req.body) check by logging it.